# What's the Data Freshness in Google Datastudio referring to?

Tags: caching, refresh, looker-studio

In Google Datastudio, one can set the Data Freshness on each Datasource.

It can be set to 1 hour, 4 hours or 12 hours but not to an explicit point in time.

Does this mean the cache is invalidated at each of these times, or will it first check whether the cache is invalid with respect to source data and only when new data has arrived will it update the cache?

E.g. -> when I have source data that is updated only every 24 hours, and I set "1 hour data freshness" will it actually invalidate the cache 24 times a day, or just once a day?

I am asking because when the source data is refreshed, it should be  reflected in the dashboards as soon as possible, on the other side I don't want to incur extra costs by setting it to "1 hour" if that would recompute the cache 23 times out of 24 unnecessarily..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Data Freshness](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020039) options represent the refresh frequency (checking and updating the report with new data from the Data Set), thus:

- 15 Minutes = Refreshing 96 times in a day (24 Hours)
- 1 Hour = Refreshing 24 times in a day (24 Hours)
- 4 Hours = Refreshing 6 times in a day (24 Hours)
- 12 Hours = Refreshing 2 times in a day (24 Hours)

Quoting from the *Refresh the cache* section of the [Data Freshness](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7020039) article:

> When the cache refreshes, all the old cached data is discarded. New queries generated by the report go directly to the underlying platform and the responses are added to the cache.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The data freshness feature is not a schedule as mentioned in the previous answer. It is a cache of the most recent requests where the recency is capped at the chosen interval.

If data freshness is set to 15 minutes, when a user checks the report and filters it for a particular value, data studio will check the cache to see if results from the same request are stored in the cache. If the query is found in the cache then it will take the results from the cache. If not, it will send a new request to the data source and store the results in the cache, setting the expiry to 15 minutes from that time.

See Google [documentation](https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/7020039#zippy=%2Cin-this-article).

> When a component in your report requests data, if that query matches a
> previously received query, then the new data request is served from
> the cache.
>
> If the request can't be served from the cache, Looker Studio requests
> the data from the underlying data set. For example, if a viewer
> changes the date range or filters the table described above by a new
> country, then Looker Studio requests the new data from the underlying
> data set. The results of that new query are then added to the table's
> cache, and Looker Studio remembers the new query for future use.